# Flutter - make a container invisible

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, containers, alignment

I'm trying to get a bar with an icon that "pops out" of it

**bar with icon**
[image: bar whit icon]

my problem is that the container containing the objects is not invisible even if I use the command: 'color: Colors.trasparent'

```dart
Widget _bottomNavigator(String uid) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Offstage(
        offstage: !_isVisible,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 20,
                color: iconColor,
              )),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightForFinite(),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: TextButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add_photo_alternate,
                  color: gradientBeginColor,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                label: Text(
                  '',
                ),
                onPressed: () async {...},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
```

Does anyone know how I can make the container no longer visible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget to control a widget's visibility.

```
Visibility(
  visible: false, // not visible if set false
  child: Container(
    ...
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried to use it but as a result all the bar disappears since the elements are its child

Comment: Wrap only the widgets that you want to control the visibility of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use with [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html), with `opacity: 0.0` then wrap the widget with `opacity`